# "Label Job" error when debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm a trying to debug an Android app, and I see this this error: [image: Label Job Error]

An internal error occurred during: "Label Job".
org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.variables.IndexedVariablePartition cannot be cast to org.eclipse.debug.core.model.IExpression

I have not been able to find the reason, any ideas? Thanks.